# How to use a swapping function without malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, swap

I would like to create void pointers without malloc. But by swapping values and the use of void pointers I do not see a solution without the use of malloc.

Is there a way to do this kind of operation without the use of malloc. I was thinking about double pointers but that is also not the solution.

..........................................................................................................................................................

```
#include <stdio.h> // Standard library functions for file input and output
#include <stdlib.h> // Standard library used for memory allocation, process control, and conversions

typedef unsigned char byte_t;

// Declaration of the function
void genericSwap(void *pdata1, void *pdata2, byte_t nBytes);

// Global variable
unsigned int dataFloat = 0; // this will help us as a flag to differentiate
                            // between a float or integer

int main() // main program
{
  int sw;             // integer value for switch
  int a = 0, b = 0;   // declaring integer a and b
  char x = 0, y = 0;  // declaring character x and y
  float c = 0, d = 0; // declaring float c and d
  for (;;)            //  infinite loop
  {
    printf("\nPlease enter your choice:\n'1' for integer value.\n'2' for "
           "character value.\n'3' for float value.\n'0' for exit. \n : ");

    scanf_s("%d", &sw); // choose the input for the switch function

    switch (sw) // switch function
    {
    case 1: // case 1 for selecting integer operations
      printf("\nPlease enter the values for a and b \n : ");
      scanf_s("%d%d", &a, &b); // choose the input for the integer operation
      printf("\nValues before swap\na=%d\tb=%d", a, b);

      genericSwap(
          &a, &b,
          sizeof(int)); // calling the swap function with address of a and b

      printf("\nValues after swap\na=%d\tb=%d", a,
             b); // printing the swap values
      break;

    case 2: // case 2 for selecting character operations
      printf("\nPlease enter the values for a and b \n : ");
      scanf_s(" %c", &x);
      scanf_s(" %c", &y);

      printf("\nValues before swap\na= %c\tb= %c", x, y);

      genericSwap(
          &x, &y,
          sizeof(char)); // calling the swap function with address of x and y

      printf("\nValues after swap\na= %c\tb= %c", x, y);
      break;
    case 3:          // case 3 for selecting float operations
      dataFloat = 1; // indicate that the float operation has been selected
      printf("\nPlease enter the values for a and b \n : ");
      scanf_s("%f%f", &c, &d);

      printf("\nValues before swap\na= %.2f\tb= %.2f", c, d);

      genericSwap(
          &c, &d,
          sizeof(float)); // calling the swap function with address of c and d

      printf("\nValues after swap\na= %.2f\tb= %.2f", c, d);
      break;

    case 0: // terminate the application
      exit(1);
      break;

    default: // when no appropriate selection has been made
      printf("\nYou have entered the wrong choice");
      break;
    }
  }
}

// define function
void genericSwap(void *pdata1, void *pdata2, byte_t nBytes) {
  void *temp = NULL; // setting void pointer temp to NULL

  temp = malloc(nBytes); // allocating memory to void pointer
  if (nBytes > 1) // if the size is more then 1 byte this means it is another
                  // value then a character
  {
    if (dataFloat == 1) // if dataFloat is equal to 1 then it is a float type
    {
      dataFloat = 0;                         // resetting dataFloat to 0
      *((float *)temp) = *((float *)pdata1); // typecasting the pointer to float
      *((float *)pdata1) = *((float *)pdata2);
      *((float *)pdata2) = *((float *)temp);

    } else {
      *((int *)temp) = *((int *)pdata1); // typecasting the pointer to integer
      *((int *)pdata1) = *((int *)pdata2);
      *((int *)pdata2) = *((int *)temp);
    }
  } else {
    *((char *)temp) = *((char *)pdata1); // typecasting the pointer to character
    *((char *)pdata1) = *((char *)pdata2);
    *((char *)pdata2) = *((char *)temp);
  }

  free(temp); // de-allocating memory

  temp = NULL; // making the pointer temp to NULL
}
```

Comment: You can swap it one byte (or some fixed size) at a time if you really don't want to allocate dynamic memory.

Comment: Another possible option if the `nBytes` is guaranteed not to be too large is to use a VLA (variable length array - e.g. `uint8_t tmpArray[nBytes];`). That's a bit more dangerous and a bit less portable. But just noting that as an option for completeness.

Comment: Don't overthink the problem. You're swapping two regions of *memory* (which had better be the same size for this to work). Use two unsigned char pointers and iterate both regions simultaneously, swapping octets along the way. harder: do the math for machine word boundaries to swap the data more efficiently for most of the region in question once you've determine this is somehow, some way, the core of some performance bottleneck you mistakenly think you need to fix.

Comment: If it's available, you can use `alloca` which allocates memory on the stack.  https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html

Comment: The code above does not care about the aliasing. it is an UB

Comment: @WhozCraig both pointers can be unaligned different way :)

Answer (score 2):

```
void *genericSwap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    uint64_t tmp;   //max size depends on the hardware architecture
    unsigned char *ua = a;
    unsigned char *ub = b;
    if(a && b)
    {
        while(size >= sizeof(tmp))
        {
            memcpy(&tmp, ua, sizeof(tmp));
            memcpy(ua, ub, sizeof(tmp));
            memcpy(ub, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
            ua += sizeof(tmp);
            ub += sizeof(tmp);
            size -= sizeof(tmp);
        }
        while(size--) 
        {
            unsigned char tmp = *ua;
            *ua++ = *ub;
            *ub++ = tmp;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

The compiler is very likely to optimize out the calls to memcpy if architecture can handle unaligned access to 32 or 64 bits data.

https://godbolt.org/z/9vxP4j

Cortex-M0 requires data to be aligned - and the compiler did not optimize the memcpy.

You can set the buffer to be much larger (in this example 64 bytes) and the compiler will also generate very efficient code: https://godbolt.org/z/vxK1vj

Comment: Notable: Even coding basic while-loop and single char swapping, one may be surprised how well the [compiler optimizes movement regardless](https://godbolt.org/z/EKxhMq).

Comment: @WhozCraig it is far from being efficient. We do not want  branches every byte which flush the pipeline etc etc. https://godbolt.org/z/qzv9bz

Comment: @WhozCraig see the second example from my answer : https://godbolt.org/z/vxK1vj

Comment: @WhozCraig clang is a bit better

Comment: Ok if it inlines the three calls to `memcpy` you use in the inner loop.

Comment: @LuisColorado you have the links. Check yourself. BTW memcpy is **safe** for generic function